# DateTime Conversion in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I changes the below xml timestamp attribute value to xs:dateTime Format.

```
<TimeValidations>
<timestamp>2017-01-30 09:30:10</timestamp>
</TimeValidations>
```

I need to convert timestamp attribute value(2002-05-30 09:30:10) to ISO 8601 format like

```
2017-01-30T09:30:10(xs:dateTime)
```

in XSLT 1.0.Can anyone help me to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm thinking in a too simple way, but if your format differs from the desired format always only in the `T` seperating date and time parts, you could use `translate`-function:

```
<xsl:template match="/TimeValidations/timestamp">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,' ', 'T')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When applied to your xml, it yields `2017-01-30T09:30:10`. Of course, you could then use this to construct an `xs:datetime` value.